# Terraria ios, is a lack of a solar eclipse a glitch or just poor luck

Tags: terraria-mobile

I am running iOS version 1.2.10061 of Terraria and I have killed The Eye of Chuthulu, The Brain of Chuthulu, The Slime King, all three mechanical bosses, Plantera, and The Golem.

After about 500 hours a solar eclipse event still has not occurred. I am wondering if this is a glitch in the game or just poor luck.

I helped a friend kill The Destroyer and he has now had two solar eclipses in less then 2 hours.

I have checked many sites for help but their content is mostly for the PC version 1.3 and I cannot find anything that refers to my problem for the iOS or mobile versions.

Comment: And then there are people like me that can't play in a world because there is a Solar eclipse 100% of the time.

Comment: Well, it's probably bad luck. I think it may help you just play the game for long periods of time then maybe a solar eclipse may happen.

Answer (score 4):

Before killing a mechanical boss the Solar Eclipse cannot occur. After defeating a mechanical boss there is a 5% chance each day of the Solar Eclipse occurring.

Were those 500 hours after killing the first mechanical boss? 500 hours equates to around 1200 in game days, assuming that you played 500 hours after defeating a mechanical boss there is a 0.000000000000000000000000001855 (1.855*10^-27) chance of never having had a Solar Eclipse event in this time.

By comparison here in Australia the chance of winning Oz Lotto Division 1 is 1 in 45 million. So the chance of not getting the Solar Eclipse after playing for 500 hours after killing a mechanical boss is about the same chance of winning Oz Lotto division 1 three times and then winning division 2.

So either your game is glitched and you should generate a new world, preferably update to the newest version too, or go and buy some Lottery tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you have provided, we cannot say with certainty that it is just poor luck, however that is the most likely scenario. It would indeed be very poor luck, however, people in my presence have failed to have Solar Eclipse events for very long periods. Not playing 8-hours a day for two months as 500 hours would imply, but definitely long periods.

The fact of the matter is that the [Solar Eclipse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse) is a random event and thus could fail to happen for an arbitrarily long time after defeating the first mechanical boss (or Plantera in the appropriate versions.) It is described as occurring "rarely". The history indicates that it was even more rare before 1.2.0.3. Although that is a PC version and I am not sure exactly how it maps to the console version.

This very frustration is probably why the 1.3 PC update included the item to force one to occur.

There is always a small possibility that it is a glitch. In which case starting a new world might help; once the appropriate bosses in that new world were defeated. (The Wall of Flesh, The Mechanical Bosses, Plantera). Since you could use your current gear in the new world defeating said bosses quickly should be far easier than it was the first time, but it would still be time consuming.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

500 hours is a little extreme and it is understandable to think that perhaps something other than bad luck is hitting you. The event is random and a fixed amount but I noticed in the particular version you are using one of the updates is "The Solar Eclipse event now has a higher chance to spawn (over time)" so it would seem your luck is even worse than one would originally think. I could not find any information on how much the increase over time would be or how long it takes for that increase to begin factoring in.

One thing I noticed though is you say your version 1.2.10061 is the most current; however, according to the [Terraria Gamepedia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_History) the current version for iOS is 1.2.10299 which was released on October 1st. One of the changes is rather vague as it just says it fixed "Minor game bug fixes". Perhaps updating to the most current version will resolve your issue. Otherwise, if everything is working as intended, it seems you just have poor luck.

Answer (score -3):

Pretty sure it's just bad luck. I'm having this problem to. 500 hours is way extreme tho. My friend just got a solar eclipse the next day after defeating the destroyer (his first mech boss.) However there is no proof that it is or isn't bad luck. I could be. Or it couldn't be. I recommended starting a new world with the newest update available defeat all mech (I dunno the criteria could of change) then wait suppose!hope this helped. Let me know if you have any lick

Comment: This doesn't really add any new information that hasn't already  been covered by the other answers, which are already 1.5 years old.